# What is the W axis in graphic?

Tags: opengl, axis, dimension

I'm learning OpenGL and im not sure what is this fourth dimension means (the x,y,z, W AXIS)?
I have tried to understand it but it looks like no one realy knows what it is..

Comment: In 3D geometry, a 4th "dimension" can be a trick to allow for translations (i.e. displacements.)

Comment: There is no `w` axis, homogenous coordinates are handy for reversible projection.

Comment: @juanchopanza You mean Time? the fourth dimension is "time"?

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman What is reversible projection?

Comment: No, not time. With three components only, it is not possible to perform translations via a multiplication of the vector and a transformation matrix. The fourth component allows this.

Comment: @Casper: Projection that is undoable. If it were irreversible, then you would not be able to go from window-space coordinates to object-space. However, because window-space coordinates preserve `w` (they are assigned `1/clip_w`), you can divide them by `w` to correctly reverse the projection.

Comment: @Casper http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#Representation

Comment: @BenBartle: Homogenous Coordinates **are not** quaternions!

Comment: See here for a very similar thread (near duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23602341/opengl-homogenous-vs-cartesian-coordinate.

Comment: @datenwolf good call.